# MVC4 how to pass value to Html.Partial in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

MVC4, on the click on dropdown item javascript function is called in view's 'scripts' section. Function makes ajax call to controller action, Json data returned. I need to pass some returned values to Html.Partial() to render in . How to accomplish that? Those value "do not exist in the current context" for Html.Partial().

VIEW : MyView

```
<div>@Html.DropDownList("listId", list, new { onChange=showText() }</div>
<div id="divMyText" ></div>

@section scripts{

function showText()
{
    var val1 = 1;

    $.ajax({
       type:"POST",
       url: "/Home/MyAction",
       data: {parm1:val1},
       success: function (result){
          renderMyView(result.id);
       }
    });
}

function renderMyView(id)
{
   $('#divMyText').html('@Html.Partial("MyView", new MyViewModel (id))');  // id here is Not 'visible' for MyViewModel. 
}

}
```

CONTROLLER actions:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(int parm1)
{
   .......
   return Json (myObject);
}

public ActionResult MyView (int id)
{
    MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel(id);
    return View(model);
}
```

How to pass id value to MyViewModel in Html.Partial statement ?
Thank you

Comment: i am afraid you cannot do like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to combine them on the controller side.  Change my action to

```
public PartialViewResult MyAction (int id)
{
    MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel(id);
    return PartialView("PartialName", model);
}
```

then in your script instead of calling your render view function

```
$('#divMyText').html(result);
```

this will take the returned partial view with the tied model and put it into the div

Comment: And no need for action MyView() ?